# Change y range at symbolic y coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I have the following tikz code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                    xbar,
                    y axis line style = {opacity = 0},
                    axis x line       = none,
                    tickwidth         = 0pt,
                    enlarge y limits  = 1.8,
                    legend style={at={(0.91,0.8)},anchor=east},
                    symbolic y coords = {2016,2009},
                    ytick             = data,
                    nodes near coords
                  ]

\addplot [color=black,fill=red]  coordinates { (8518,2009)     (10891,2016) };
\addplot [color=black,fill=blue] coordinates { (5827,2009)     (5845,2016)  }; 

\legend{DEB,LMR}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me this:

[image]

The tiikz plot is included into my main .tex file via

```
 \begin{figure}[!htb]                                                                             
    \centering                                                                                   
    \input{barchart.tex}                         
    \caption{Here is the description of the plot}                                   
    \label{fig:barchartplot}
 \end{figure}
```

However, there is much empty space above and below the bars. How can I "clip" this image? Above and below there is much text and I dont want to have so much "white area" around the image!

Thanks an advance for you help!

André

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `bar width` is 10pt and the sep between two bars at the same y-value is 2pt (`xbar=2pt` is default). You have two plots and so the space needed between `2009` and `2016` is at least (2*10pt+2pt)+2pt=24pt. So you can use

```
y=30pt,
enlarge y limits={abs=15pt}% the value must be at least half of y
```

Then you have to remove `enlarge y limits  = 1.8` and to change the `legend style`. One possibility is

```
legend style={at={(1,1-|{axis cs:10891,2016})},anchor=north east},
```

[image]

Another

```
legend style={at={(1,1-|{axis cs:10891,2016})},anchor=south east},
```

[image]

There are other possibilities too.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                    y=30pt,
                    enlarge y limits={abs=15pt},
                    xbar,
                    y axis line style = {opacity = 0},
                    axis x line       = none,
                    tickwidth         = 0pt,
                    %legend style={at={(1,1-|{axis cs:10891,2016})},anchor=north east},
                    legend style={at={(1,1-|{axis cs:10891,2016})},anchor=south east},
                    symbolic y coords = {2016,2009},
                    ytick             = data,
                    nodes near coords
                  ]

\addplot [color=black,fill=red]  coordinates { (8518,2009)     (10891,2016) };
\addplot [color=black,fill=blue] coordinates { (5827,2009)     (5845,2016)  }; 

\legend{DEB,LMR}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks for the great explaination, working like a charm! :-)